# Install memcached with php5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, memcached

Dears,

I was trying to install memcached with php version 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 to use it in a Symfnoy2 project, when I faced this error after installing my composer packages:

> Declaration of Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Cache\LoggingMemcache::get() should be compatible with Memcached::get($key, $cache_cb = NULL, &$cas_token = NULL, &$udf_flags = NULL) in /vendor/leaseweb/memcache-bundle/Lsw/MemcacheBundle/Cache/LoggingMemcache.php

I've been searching for a solution for this problem for hours with no luck.

My composer file for this bundle:

```
{
"require" : {
        ...
        "leaseweb/memcache-bundle": "1.2.*",
        ...
    },
}
```

My php.ini file for memcache and memcached:
[image: My php.ini file for memcache and memcached]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also test on 2.1.0 for bundle?

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Great, the bundle has been installed successfully and the error has gone away, but I got a new error:
`Unrecognized options "client" under "lsw_memcache.session"`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's about bundle configs. Maybe there is new config.yml rows for new version. My advice is check the new readme/github repo for bundle.

Comment: OK, then where can I find the corresponding configurations for the different versions of this bundle? I've tried to find them on the documentation, but, unfortunately, just the latest configurations are available there. Any help!

Comment: Firstly check here for configs http://knpbundles.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle 

Secondly I don't know why you are using memcache*. My advice is Redis and SncRedisBundle if you are not have problem loading Redis to your server.

Comment: I already use Redis in almost all the new features, but this is an old project and there are many features that are already implemented based on Memcache. I am planning to shift them all to Redis but that's on my backlog tasks to be done. Any ways, thank you for your advice :)